# Equation (3.23) GP for ML book

Tags: variance, gaussian-process, laplace-approximation

This is the computation of the variance when we do Laplace Approximation for inference in binary classification. I do not understand why the variance is decomposed into these two terms.

[image]

Comment: This is the definition of variance.

Comment: Yes, you are using the definition of variance but something else.

Comment: Related? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.